# авторизация в laravel с другого домена

Tags: reactjs, laravel7

Всем привет!
Хочу разобраться с авторизацией в laravel с другого домена и у меня такая архитектура:
Есть приложение ReactJS, которое работает на http://localhost:3000, а также backend http://carbon.ru на laravel на виртуальной машине(vmware). На backend я создал route в файле routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

И пытаюсь стучаться к этому backend по адресу http://carbon.ru/login с помощью запроса:

```
   axios.post('http://carbon.ru/api/login',
                {
                    email:"gggg@gmail.com",
                    password: '12312312',
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        // 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : token,
                        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': "значение которое я подсмотрел на backend при обычной авторизации" ,
                    },

                },
                )
                .then(response => {

                });
```

Но у меня постоянно вылазит ошибка: "message": "CSRF token mismatch." И я никак не пойму где мне в моем приложенни на React получить этот токен для передачи его в заголовках. Я совсем новичек в laravel поэтому надеюсь, что, даже если я не верно формулирую вопрос, меня все же правильно поймут. К слову скажу что если добавить в исключения проверки csrf api/login

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        "/api/login"
    ];
 }
```

то все работает. Может кто нибудь поделиться секретом как это правильно сделать. Как с бекенда передать в reactJs токен и как его правильно отправить бекенду для авторизации?

Comment: CSRF не предназначен для защиты api. Используйте [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) или другие средства для auth. Сам я в большинстве случае использую lumen (jwt-auth) + angular, токен передаётся в заголовке authorization

Answer (score 0):

В laravel 7 появилась крутая штука [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)

Для авторизации SPA, мобильном приложениях

В целом, установка простая, в доке все описано пошагово.

Comment: спасибо! Но здесь все же необходим общий домен первого уровня. А мне очень интересен вопрос связанный с различными доменами.

Comment: @AndreyOv Тогда есть сложный путь :)

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport

Comment: спасибо! Похоже, то что нужно.